# OpenStack redundant shared storage backend solution

Tags: nfs, openstack, ceph, shared-storage

Which storage backends are recommended for OpenStack which allows live migration and shared storage?
Is it NFS / Ceph / storage backend drivers to commercial storage solutions? Which of these is better?
In VMware vSphere it's possible to use iSCSI target on all the hosts because there's VMFS.
Is iSCSI really not suitable for OpenStack on bare-metal hosts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dedicated Cephs nodes with local storage are *a* common option where Ceph provides block and file storage.

Comment: What are the alternatives? just for my own knowledge. Only NFS? it seems to me that iSCSI is not a good idea for multiple hosts as shared storage. Unlike in vSphere where the VMFS makes it possible

Comment: There are several reasons to pick either NFS or ISCSI but on both cases an overlay service would be required - indeed similar to vSphere and VMFS. I would suggest reading up on things like Cinder and Manila: 

https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/Cinder
https://docs.openstack.org/security-guide/shared-file-systems.html

Comment: It's not clear to me how is it done similarly to vSphere and VMFS with iSCSI

Comment: With Vmware you have vSphere that connects to ISCSI, manages volumes and makes sure you can use them for virtual machines and vmfs provides the shared filed system.

In Openstack you have Ceph, Cinder and actually quite a few other services that manage volumes and make sure you can use them for virtual machines. And you can use several shared file systems. Another nice doc to check:

https://docs.openstack.org/arch-design/design-storage/design-storage-concepts.html